# Ubuntu 12.10 BCM 4313 Wireless N Issue

Tags: wireless, 12.10, broadcom, hp

I have a hp dv6-7014nr and I just installed ubuntu on it and after some trouble I have my wireless working for the most part.  The one last problem I have is that *wireless N still is not working*, I can only access G networks.

My wireless card is the `BCM4313 broadcom wireless adapter`.I am using the `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an alternative installer perhaps the b43fwcutter which can sometimes do a better job with other wifi elements such as N

Open up a terminal and type this.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

Then get it switched on by trying the following

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb
sudo modprobe b43
```

Have a go and let us know if it works